# How to make my query return string rather than an array?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I ran this code and it is returning an array. Please, how can I make it return only a user_id and not arrays of user_id?

```
     $userr = DB::table('level_one_models')
        ->select('user_id')
        ->where('downline', '<=', 7)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: I want to fetch the user_id as an integer. The query above is returning user_id as an array.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `$userr` to be the `user_id` you could just do:

```
$userr = DB::table('level_one_models')
    ->select('user_id')
    ->where('downline', '<=', 7)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->first()
    ->user_id;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

Comment: First method is throwing error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: My downline column holds email addresses and I want the downline column counted. I think my approach is wrong. Please how can I count the downline column?